# 403 Forbidden Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Saludos tengo un error al cargar las imagenes en codeigniter como se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La ruta de las imagenes estan bien dado que el mismo sistema funciona perfecto en windows el problema surge en ubuntu , quiza sea algo de permisos he intentado :

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/aressoftwarecontrol
```

después he reiniciado el apache pero sin exito, quiza alguna sugerencia gracias.

mi htaccess es:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
Captura de pantalla de 2020-01-08 21-31-53
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Las imagenes las muestro algo asi:

```
<?php foreach ($lista as $lt) { ?>
..
    <img src="<?php echo base_url().'application/modules/Fuerzas/photos/'.$lt->logoFuerza; ?>" height="50px" width="50px">
...
...
```

Estructura de carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir también el código php que ocupas para guardar y mostrar una fotito de la estructura de tus carpetas (para asegurarnos de que existan)?

Comment: Listo he agregado como muestro las imagenes

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas guardando y mostrando una imagen pero que esta imagen esté fuera y al mismo nivel que application? Ponle a la carpeta algo así como assets y dentro de esta carpeta pega una imagen. Me da la impresión que por el simple hecho de estar tratando de entrar a la carpeta de application y por el htaccess usado codeigniter te está rechazando. Haz lo que te dije anteriormente y dime cómo te fue.

Comment: Gracias, pero en efecto tambien tengo una imagen en assets en una carpeta "img" que uso como logo pero tiene el mismo resultado no carga

Comment: En tu .htaccess también veo que agregaste esta frase: Captura de pantalla de 2020-01-08 21-31-53 Creo que eso te podría estar dando error, trata de removerla, después borras tu caché y puedes intentarlo de nuevo a ver si te jala bien.

Comment: Revisas **todos** los archivos `.htaccess` de las carpetas, desde la carpeta raíz hasta cada una de las carpetas anidadas. El error 403 indica que has restringido el acceso a alguna de las carpetas y se necesita un usuario/password para acceder a ella.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve replicando tu error y parece ser que encontré el problema.

El problema principal lo encuentras en el `.htaccess` que está dentro de tu carpeta `application` el cual es en tu caso este:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
Captura de pantalla de 2020-01-08 21-31-53
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Para que no tengas problemas en acceder a las imágenes dentro tu carpeta de application vas a tener que quitar el .htaccess o remover todo dentro de él que luzca de esta forma:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Quitando estas directivas vas a poder acceder a las imágenes que están en tu estructura de proyecto.

Este es el ejemplo del problema que estás teniendo con tu `.htaccess` y que te regresa el error 403

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y te muestro ahora cómo el servidor ya no retorna un error 404 una vez quitando el `.htaccess` de tu carpeta application:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal seria que tus imágenes se encontraran dentro de un directorio al nivel raíz de nombre **assets** incluso hay mismo podrías manejar subcarpetas como **js**, **css**, **photos o img**.

Y para mandar a llamar a cualquier imagen almacenada en dicha carpeta basta con ponerlo:

```
<?php base_url('assets/img/tuimagen.png'); ?>
```

Tu error básicamente lo ocasiona el `.htaccess` debido a los permisos que tiene asignados, es por eso que al ponerlo a nivel raíz no te generaría dichos errores, aunque ya te dieron alguna solución que no recomiendo ya que desproteger los directorios de **application** puede ocasionarte problemas de seguridad.

Aparte puedes agregar el archivo **index.html** a las carpetas que te mencione que crearas para que no puedan entrar directamente a los directorios y listar los archivos o bien hacerlo desde el mismo `.htaccess`.